# Height and width of text block as per text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to set the height and width of text block as per the text?The text is given to the text block dynamically ?

```
 TextBlock myTextBlockj = new TextBlock() 
   { Text = "Hello World", 
     Width =150, 
     Height = 40, 
     FontSize = 20 
   };
```

The text of text block is "Hello World".I want to set width of text block of size same as text.If text changes the width of text block should change.

Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: Ya its possible but depends on your xaml tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap

In Code:

```
TextBlock myTextBlockj = new TextBlock() 
{
    Text = "Hello World", 
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, 
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, 
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
};
```

In Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello world" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Also, you might need [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case the text exceeds the available space.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the VerticalAlignment and the HorizontalAlignments to something other than stretch.

Here is a one page example:

```
<Window x:Class="TextblockMinSize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in code you have:

```
TextBlock myTextBlockj = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "Hello World",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
};
```

Comment: Setting the ALIGNMENT would not set width of text block as per the text.

Comment: Mihir, you need width and height set to Auto as well, but after then, yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

For Height you may try

```
LineHeight="Auto"
```